# lost the ability to view memory, etc via Eclipse CDT debug perspective

Tags: eclipse, debugging, eclipse-cdt

I've noticed that once you close a window (such as the memory view) in the Eclipse CDT debugger there's no obvious way to make it re-appear.  As I'm on a MacBook and still haven't mastered the darned touchpad, I tend to click things by accident and one by one, various useful windows within the CDT debug perspective are going away, apparently never to be seen again.  Does anyone know how to make these things come back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Window->Show View-> Memory View
```

If Memory View is not present in the list, press "Other" and type memory view. It should appear.